# What information does the game center return after finding players?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I am currently experimenting on raywenderlich's project of [How To Make a Multiplayer iPhone Game Hosted on Your Own Server Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server)

at the end of the part 1 tutorial, it claims that after looking for auto-match via the game center panel, the log panel would show 2 PlayerIDs

```
    CatRace[5407:707] didFindPlayers
    CatRace[5407:707] G:1036727375
    CatRace[5407:707] G:1417937643
```

However, when I tried to run on the iPhone Simulator and my iPhone, it always returns only 1 playerID after finished matching players.

So, I would like to know exactly how the function would return the information.

Could anyone help on this ?

Additional:
I found that the simulator and the iDevice found the player of another, but not including itself. Is it the normal case?

Already tried to put the server on to an external host. Still No luck, returning only one player in the array.

Is this function

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDs
```

supposed to return all the players including the local player ?

Comment: Are you logged in to Game Center with different accounts on each device?

Comment: Gordon: Yes. I tried 3 different accounts, both testing and real accounts.

Comment: Would it matter if the devices are in the same wifi network ?

Comment: Regardless of the wired return, could I just add the localplayers' playerID into the array in order to solve the problem ?

Comment: Just tried to start a 3 players game with 3 different accounts, it returned 2 playerIds and again, that of the local player was again excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is so wired, I manage to manipulate the return into a new NSMUTABLEARRAY and send to the hosting server.

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDs {

NSMutableArray *players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:playerIDs];

[players insertObject:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID atIndex:0];

if (_state == NetworkStatePendingMatch) {

[self dismissMatchmaker];
[self sendStartMatch:players];

}

[players release];
```

However, I am still looking for the answer of my original question, which is the supposed return of - (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindPlayers:(NSArray *)playerIDs